# Round, yellow you rap them on a stone and they go ding

Tags: dialogue, once-upon-a-time-in-the-west

In *Once Upon a Time in the West*, Cheyenne is telling Jill that there is a whole heap of whys, and then he says

"Round, yellow, you know the kind, you rap them around a stone and they go ding..." and she replies that she knows the kind.

What are they talking about?

Comment: You may have the quote wrong: The only source I could find for this quotes it as: *"Round. Yellow. You know the kind. You wrap ‘em on a stone and they go ‘ding!”* and I'm thinking it should be "rap" not "wrap".

Comment: @Catija: I got the quote from the movie (in real time), although with the subtitles, so "rap" and "wrap" could be a mistake. I'm not a native English speaker, so it seems like a highly plausible mistake to make.

Comment: If it's "rap them on a stone", it could be a gold coin. So he's talking about money.

Comment: @Catija: That makes a lot of sense. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. (Strangely, searching "rap them on a stone" (with the quotation marks) in Google and DuckDuckGo found me only one page for the script of this movie and some Arabic translations of this sentence.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sources](http://notesofafilmfanatic.com/?p=379) I've found for the [quote](http://www.allreadable.com/mv1f429Ibvi) state that it's actually:

> *"Round. Yellow. You know the kind. You wrap/rap ‘em **on** a stone and they go ‘ding!”*

And I'm guessing that the homophones "rap" and "wrap" are confused in this example... it's a common mistake.

So, if that's the case, I'm guessing that he's talking about gold coins, or generally money. So the "whole heap of whys" is a pile of gold coins.